# How to execute a function when a variable's value is changed?

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-10

In Odoo 10, I want to change the value of a variable when the forecasted quantity of a product is changed. I tried using the @api.onchange decorator, but it doesn't work. The forecasted quantity change, but the variable keeps the same value. I have this:

```
class MyProduct(models.Model):    
    _inherit = 'product.product'       
    was_changed = fields.Boolean(default = False)    
    @api.onchange('virtual_available')    
        def qtychanged(self):        
            self.was_changed = True        
            _logger.info('Product_Qty_Cahnged:  %s',str(self.virtual_available))
```

In this code, if the forecasted quantity of a product would change, the variable was_changed should be set to True, but nothing happens.

After that, I tried to overwrite the write method for my custom class, like this:

```
class MyProduct(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'product.product'
    was_changed = fields.Boolean(default=False)

    @api.multi
    def write(self, values):
        if values['virtual_available']:
            values['was_changed'] = True
        # THE FOLLOWING LINES WERE IN THE ORIGINAL WRITE METHOD
        res = super(MyProduct, self).write(values)
        if 'standard_price' in values:
            self._set_standard_price(values['standard_price'])
        return res
```

But still, I have the same result. I can't seem to get that flag to change. So, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class MyProduct(models.Model):    
      _inherit = 'product.product'       
      was_changed = fields.Boolean(default = False)    
      @api.onchange('virtual_available')    
      def qtychanged(self):        
          self.write({'was_changed': True})        
          _logger.info('Product_Qty_Cahnged:  %s',str(self.virtual_available))
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, still have the same behavior...I looked for the message in the odoo-server.log, it doesn't seem to be executing the function, since the message couldn't be found.

Comment: Did you add this file into __init__.py file.

Comment: It has the standard "import models" declaration

Comment: There is another __init__.py file inside models folder. Import your file inside this init file too.

Comment: You're right, but the file was already imported to that __init__.py (the one inside the models folder). Still the same result